# I need a field that accepts both text and images

Tags: html, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm developing a JSF page that includes ADF components in Jdeveloper 11gR2

I want to insert in this page a text box or anything like a field that accepts text and images. In other words, users can write text and paste images in this field.

What field should I choose here?

So please any help or link that might help me?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to have a single component for image upload and text input Or you want to be able to drag and drop an image onto a component that takes text as input?

Comment: i need a component that accepts images and text. my form is an email form i need the user to write text and be able to drag images inside this field. (Like ms outlook body)

Comment: That's a rich text editor you already used before posting this question. Choose the one which you like the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `af:richTextEditor` It will let you add both text and images

Comment: af:richTextEditor only supports text wil styling, you cannot insert images into this  box.

Comment: Did you try to copy and paste the image in richTextEditor? It will let you do that, like any advance editors. Try it out here http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/richTextEditor.jspx

Comment: thank you man, i tried it on the link and i was able to copy/past images in it. but in Jdeveloper i insert a rich text Editor but i am not able to past images in it, i'm trying now to search if there is a condition or anything to enable images in this rich text editor

Comment: You can get the code for richTextEditor from that link itself. There is a ViewSource button on the top.

Comment: now it worked :) the problem was with my browser, it doesnt work on google chrome but it work on others thanks